# calculate mean across 3 dimensional array of different length

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 3 dimensional array with dimensions n * d * m. However, ni can vary. It looks something like this

```
[[[1,1,3],  [[3,2,1],  [[4,3,2],  
  [3,4,2]],  [3,4,2],   [5,2,3]]]
             [4,5,3]],
```

I need to calculate the mean across all data points. I was using the `scipy.stats.mean` function and but threw error about mismatching dimensions. Therefore, I was thinking about padding the array to the largest ni so that it has uniform dimensions something like this

```
[[[  1,  1,  3],  [[3,2,1],  [[  4,  3,  2],  
  [  3,  4,  2],   [3,4,2],   [  5,  2,  3],
  [NaN,NaN,NaN]],  [4,5,3]],  [NaN,NaN,NaN]]]
```

but I don't know if this is the best solution or how I could calculate the mean with NaN.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just using [numpy.mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)?

Comment: @Killrawr - I did. `numpy.mean` returns `nan`.

Comment: Your example does not look like a 3D array.

Comment: @eumiro the example `[ (first dim) [ (second dim) [1,1,3],  [(third dim) [3,2,1]]]]` is 3D (Open it in notepad++ to see bracket endings)

Comment: @Killraws with numpy.mean I get an error about mismatching dimensions. I need the mean for the entire dataset. To be precise, I need both the mean and standard deviation to calculate the zscore, but first only the mean

Comment: I'd just suggest just writing a loop, keeping a count throughout the loop as you increase the total and then dividing by the count (But this pretty much depends on the size of your array, in terms of computation and whether its going to be worth it).

Comment: @bizso09 - the brackets do not match.

Comment: @eumiro: they do, but the reading order is odd. [5,2,3] is the last row of the last 2d submatrix.

Comment: That is, it makes more sense in the form `[[[1,1,3],[3,4,2]],[[3,2,1],[3,4,2],[4,5,3]],[[4,3,2],[5,2,3]]]`

Comment: @Junuxx - oh, I see now… using Python syntax for Python questions would be better.

Comment: @bizso09 - please use Python syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html):

```
>>> from numpy import ma, nan
>>> a = ma.array([[1,1,3], [3,4,2], [nan,nan,nan]], mask=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
>>> b = ma.array([[3,2,1], [3,4,2], [4,5,3]])
>>> c = ma.array([[4,3,2], [5,2,3], [nan,nan,nan]], mask=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
>>> X = ma.array([a, b, c])
```

Then taking the mean over any axis will ignore the masked values:

```
>>> X.mean(axis=0)
masked_array(data =
 [[2.66666666667 2.0 2.0]
 [3.66666666667 3.33333333333 2.33333333333]
 [4.0 5.0 3.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> X.mean(axis=1)
masked_array(data =
 [[2.0 2.5 2.5]
 [3.33333333333 3.66666666667 2.0]
 [4.5 2.5 2.5]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> X.mean(axis=2)
masked_array(data =
 [[1.66666666667 3.0 --]
 [2.0 3.0 4.0]
 [3.0 3.33333333333 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is actually `[[[1,1,3],[3,4,2]],[[3,2,1],[3,4,2],[4,5,3]],[[4,3,2],[5,2,3]]]` which it should be as you mention you have a 3-dimensional array, then the average can be found using loops :

```
>>> l = [[[1,1,3],[3,4,2]],[[3,2,1],[3,4,2],[4,5,3]],[[4,3,2],[5,2,3]]]
>>> s = 0; n=0;

>>> for i in l:    #First loop traverses through the first dimension
        for j in i:    #Traverses through the second dimension
            s += sum(j)
            n += len(j)


>>> print("Average is ", s/n)
Average is  2.85714
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all numpy array functions fail because your object is a list of 2D arrays rather than a 3D numpy array.

A solution is to unroll the list and compute the means separately. In your case this will be:

```
In [23]: import numpy as np

In [24]: L = np.array([[[1,1,3],[3,4,2]],
                  [[3,2,1],[3,4,2],[4,5,3]],[[4,3,2],[5,2,3]]])

In [28]: Lsum = ( np.sum(L[0]) + np.sum(L[1]) + np.sum(L[2]) ) 

In [29]: Lmean = Lsum.astype(float) \ 
                   / ( np.size(L[0]) + np.size(L[1]) + np.size(L[2]) )

In [46]: Lmean
Out[46]: 2.8571428571428572
```

This can be put into a loop for varying 3rd dimension...